# Get "time of upload started"

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm developing a WebAPI service in which you can upload a file. The Action looks something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostAsync(byte[] content)
{
   var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

The client which are using the WebAPI also provides a timestamp as header which is used together with some HMAC-stuff to authenticate. One part of the auth check is to validate the timestamp. We parse the timestamp and checks if it is +/- 5 minutes from `now`. If not then the auth fails.
It works great for all our API calls except this upload API (in some cases). The problem is that sometimes a user uploads a large file over a slow connection and therefore it takes more than 5 minutes to upload the file and the point in time where we check is AFTER the whole file has been uploaded.

Therefore:

1. Can we somehow do the HMAC check BEFORE the whole file is uploaded? (the file itself (HTTP Content) is not used in the HMAC check). Today we are using an `ActionFilter`.
2. Can I get the "time of request" (first byte arrived or whatever) in my Action code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some investigation I came up with a much better solution:
Use a HTTP Module to do the actual HMAC authentication.

After reading this blog post (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/08/30/iis-7-0-asp-net-pipelines-modules-handlers-and-preconditions.aspx) I got a much better understanding of how IIS Works.

I decided to use a HTTP Module which is invoked before the MVC Action.

The code ended up like this:

```
public class HmacModule : IHttpModule
{
   public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        EventHandlerTaskAsyncHelper taskAsyncHelper = new EventHandlerTaskAsyncHelper(Authenticate);
        context.AddOnBeginRequestAsync(taskAsyncHelper.BeginEventHandler, taskAsyncHelper.EndEventHandler);
    }

    private async Task Authenticate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
        var request = context.Request;

        var authResponse = await CheckAuthentication(request);

        if (!authResponse.HasAccess)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            context.Response.StatusDescription = authResponse.ErrorMessage;
            if (authResponse.Details != null)
                context.Response.Write(authResponse.Details);

            context.Response.End();
        }
    }
 }
```

I hope this helps others in the same situation...